# list.files function is returnign an empty list?

Tags: r, list, file

I'm not familiar with this function. I'm basically copying a team member's script in order to combine 22 files into 1. First I'm listing the 22 directories as a character vector, and calling it 'folders'. Then this is how I use list.file:

```
sumstats_list <- list.files(folders, full.names=T) %>%
        mclapply(fread, mc.cores = 6)
sumstats_list
```

The results is just 'list()'.
And for reference, this is what folders looks like:

```
 [1] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr1.txt"
 [2] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr2.txt"
 [3] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr3.txt"
 [4] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr4.txt"
 [5] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr5.txt"
 [6] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr6.txt"
 [7] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr7.txt"
 [8] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr8.txt"
 [9] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr9.txt"
[10] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr10.txt"
[11] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr11.txt"
[12] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr12.txt"
[13] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr13.txt"
[14] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr14.txt"
[15] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr15.txt"
[16] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr16.txt"
[17] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr17.txt"
[18] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr18.txt"
[19] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr19.txt"
[20] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr20.txt"
[21] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr21.txt"
[22] "/z/Comp/lu_group/Members/jwlorge/ATN/scripts/PRS/ouputs/prs_output/prs_cs/factor1_pst_eff_a1_b0.5_phiauto_chr22.txt"
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Seems like `folders` is already a list of files. What do you hope to get out of `list.files`? It expects the input to be directories, not files.

Comment: @GregorThomas I believe the mcapply with fread is meant to read the contents of each of these files so they can be combined. So sumstats_list should be the contents of all the files, But I didn't write this part of the script so that's why I'm confused.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: What `list.files` does is make a vector of file names. The `folders` that you show is already a vector of file names. So I think the `list.files` is not needed and you want `sumstats_list <- folders %>% mclapply(fread, mc.cores = 6)`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have to stick with `fread`, package {vroom} offers a [convenient approach](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/05/vroom-1-0-0/#reading-multiple-files). Because of vroom's speed you might not even have to parallelize the import.
Example:

```
library(vroom)

file_list <- fs::dir_ls(glob = "path/to/input/files/*.txt")
sumstats_combined <- vroom(file_list)
```

Comment: `fread` has run in parallel by default since version 1.11.0 (2018), so OP probably doesn't need to explicitly parallelize at all. (`vroom` also runs in parallel by default.)